# How to send model data to another component in Angular after a button click

Tags: angular

On `component A` I have a an array of Products, these are shown in a list and at the end of each is an option to view that Product.

Each Product has an array of items attached to it, and when I click on view the product, I want `Component B` to show a list of these items.

I cannot figure out how to pass the Product that I click on to the next component. I have tried with `@Input()` as per the angular website, but I dont think this is the correct way as the two components are not a child / parent.

So if I click view on the first `Product` in `Component A`, it should open up `component B` and display a list of items that are contained in the first `Product` using an `ngFor let item of model.items`

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you showed your code, but if you are saying the components are not child components, and you are routing between two different components on click, then what you want to do is not pass the product, but instead pass only the product id to the second component and re-look up the product once you get there. So set your data up like this:

```
products = [
  {id: 1, name: 'product 1' items: []}
];
```

then you want to pass the id ONLY to your next component:

```
<div [routerLink]="['/product-detail']" [queryParams]="{id: product.id}" >{{product.name}}</div>
```

then on the detail component, you will need to lookup the product using and ActivatedRoute.

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {  }

 this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    this.id = params['id'] || 0;
    // now look up the product
}
```

Hope that makes sense.